# Only render page if app.use('/api') on Express 4

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, routes

I have the following:

**app.js**

```
...

var api = require('./routes/api');
app.use('/', api);
app.use('/api', api);
```

**./routes/api**

```
...

var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }), function (req, res) {
    res.json({
        msg: 'API is running'
    });
});
```

How would I differentiate between the `/` and `/api` route so that I could render a page if i'm on `/` and return only JSON if i'm on `/api`?

I was thinking of passing a function to non-api routes to render a json response, and another function to api routes to display the json response?

Any other way to do this, or am I just overthinking it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for [req.baseUrl](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#req.baseUrl), but it wouldn't use this. Is there a reason why you don't use the suffix to differ between the response types:  `/api/resource/id.json` and `/api/resource/id.xml`, or if no suffix is supplied use the `Accept` header to determine the type?

Comment: Looked into the accept header, https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/error-pages/index.js#L65 So I could use `if (req.accepts('html')) {` for my `/` route and `if (req.accepts('json')) {` for `/api` ?

Comment: You would need to usethat way `req.accepts(['json', 'html'])` ans check what is returned,  because the requests are often in that format `Accept: application/json, */*;q=0.1`, so your first `req.accepts('html')`  would also match because of the `*/*;q=0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you mounting 2 paths on the same route file i.e.

```
var api = require('./routes/api');
app.use('/', api);
app.use('/api', api);
```

You can use:

```
var api = require('./routes/api');
var index = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api', api);
```

Now, you can write your routes in these 2 files. `/` in index file will be use for `domain.com/` url, and `/` route in api file will be used for `domain.com/api` url. Now, you can handle both requests as differently as you want.

You could also specify both routes in index file(in this case, you do not need to create api file and mount it on a path). e.g.

```
router.get('/', function( req, res ){
  // code for / path here
});

router.get('/api', function( req, res ){
  // code for /api path here
});
```

Comment: Because I want to run the same function from both ends from any router.get etc. But I guess I could still call the same function from an external controller?

Comment: @Sanction You mean you want the same function to be called on both routes e.g. /login and /api/login ?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends what you want.

Example from one of my projects:

We had the frontend under `/client/` so when we got `/` we used a `res.redirect('/client/')` where your HTML file could be.

Or maybe something like `res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])` fits your needs

Take a look at [Express Documentaion for res](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res) there are many possibilities.